# Why does std::tuple call operator <=> twice?

Tags: c++, spaceship-operator

The following code calls operator <=> twice, with arguments reversed. But why?

GCC 10.2 and clang 12 both seem to be using libstdc++-10, whose <tuple> does provide operator <=>, so it doesn’t appear to be a case of missing standard library support and my code has to be incorrect. How to fix it?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <compare>
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    int i;
    auto operator <=>(X const& other) const {
        std::cout << this << " <=> " << &other << std::endl;
        return i <=> other.i;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::tuple{X{42}} <=> std::tuple{X{42}};
}
```

Comment: @IgorR. Are you implying that X is not three_way_comparable?

Comment: Isn't that to be expected? It has to deliver one of three? `a < b`, `b < a` or equal? Like, `return a < b ? -1 : b < a ? 1 : 0` which also requires 2 comparisons in 2/3 of the cases.

Comment: @TedLyngmo But X::operator <=> can answer the question in one invocation, that’s the entire reason it exists.

Comment: @RomanOdaisky It generates the operators for you. I don't see how it could make some comparisons go away.

Comment: @TedLyngmo all that operators are removed in C++ 20

Comment: @armagedescu No they are still there. You can replace your implementations of them with `<=>` but, old code still works and the code generated by `<=>` will likely be doing very similar things to what the old code did.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, The way to make the comparisons go away is for `tuple` of one element to forward its `operator<=>` call to that element when possible. The multiple comparisons would be pushed down to `int`s instead of `X`s. I believe the question is trying to figure out why that doesn't happen.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the own implementation in OP uses operator ```<=>```. The operators <, > and so on are not removed themselves. These are removed from tuple implementation, and left only ```<=>```

Comment: Hmm, yeah, you are probably correct all of you. :-) I'll get back to cooking dinner.

Comment: From stepping through in gdb, I see that `X` fails the `three_way_comparable_with` concept, so it falls back to use `<` twice, which is ends up calling the overload twice. Not sure why `three_way_comparable_with` is not being met.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: You need to define `operator==` for `X`.

`std::tuple` compares elements via a synthesized three-way comparison that uses `<=>` only if the type satisfies `std::three_way_comparable_with<T,U>`. Ultimately, this requires [`std::three_way_comparable<X>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cmp.concept#concept:three_way_comparable), which requires an expositionary `weakly-equality-comparable-with` concept. As you might guess, this requires `==` to be valid.

The fix is a one-liner:

```
bool operator==(X const& other) const = default;
```

Now why is `==` required when `<=>` seems to do the job on its own here? I can only speculate, but it might be due to concepts being more "complete" than we're used to with only needing `operator<` for example. If a type is comparable with `<=>`, it should really also support equality.

As for why `<=>` does not cover `==` on its own unless defaulted, this is because of the performance pitfall for classes whose equality can short-circuit (such as vectors and strings) as well as any classes that contain such types. No indication would be given that equality compares every element instead of short-circuiting, so `<=>` does not handle equality unless it can guarantee that you'll avoid that pitfall (via defaulting `<=>`).